# Finding a file using AppleScript

Tags: macos, file, applescript

someone please explain why this won't work. The script alone without the "if mainReturned = "File" then" works just fine but when I add it to another part of a script, things get weird. It highlights the word "on" on the 5th to last line of the script and then stops working etc. Please explain how I can fix it to add it to another script? The gist of the other script is basically if you enter a word the script will bring certain things up such as if I were to enter the work "File" it performs this. But it won't work. Its the format of if mainReturned = "File" then

nothing really this is kinda the only code I could minimize the script to

```
                    set SearchDir to choose folder
                            set SearchTerm to text returned of ¬
        (display dialog "Enter your search term below:" default answer "" with icon file "Macintosh HD:Users:<insert user's name.:Documents:robot-icon.png")
        set theResults to SpotlightSearch(SearchTerm, SearchDir)
        if theResults is not {""} then
            set theChoice to choose from list theResults with prompt ¬
                "Here are the files that match the search term \"" & SearchTerm & ¬
                "\" in directory \"" & SearchDir & "\":" cancel button name ¬
                "Quit" OK button name "Reveal in Finder"
            if theChoice is not false then
                tell application "Finder"
                    activate
                    reveal (POSIX file theChoice) as alias
                end tell
            end if
        else
            display dialog "No Results Found." buttons ¬
                {"Quit", "Search Again"} default button 2 with icon file "Macintosh HD:Users:<insert user's name>:Documents:robot-icon.png"
            if button returned of result is "Quit" then exit repeat
        end if
        on SpotlightSearch(SearchTerm, SearchDir)
            set theResults to paragraphs of ¬
                (do shell script "mdfind " & quoted form of SearchTerm & ¬
                    " -onlyin " & quoted form of POSIX path of SearchDir)
        end SpotlightSearch
```

my expected results is -

```
        if mainReturned = "File" then
display dialog "Keyword '" & mainReturned & "' is being executed..." buttons {"OK"} default button 1 with title "Auto-Web" with icon file "Macintosh HD:Users:<insert user name>:Documents:robot-icon.png" giving up after 1
        set SearchDir to choose folder
                    set SearchTerm to text returned of ¬
        (display dialog "Enter your search term below:" default answer "" with icon file "Macintosh HD:Users:<insert user's name.:Documents:robot-icon.png")
        set theResults to SpotlightSearch(SearchTerm, SearchDir)
        if theResults is not {""} then
            set theChoice to choose from list theResults with prompt ¬
                "Here are the files that match the search term \"" & SearchTerm & ¬
                "\" in directory \"" & SearchDir & "\":" cancel button name ¬
                "Quit" OK button name "Reveal in Finder"
            if theChoice is not false then
                tell application "Finder"
                    activate
                    reveal (POSIX file theChoice) as alias
                end tell
            end if
        else
            display dialog "No Results Found." buttons ¬
                {"Quit", "Search Again"} default button 2 with icon file "Macintosh HD:Users:<insert user's name>:Documents:robot-icon.png"
            if button returned of result is "Quit" then exit repeat
        end if
        on SpotlightSearch(SearchTerm, SearchDir)
            set theResults to paragraphs of ¬
                (do shell script "mdfind " & quoted form of SearchTerm & ¬
                    " -onlyin " & quoted form of POSIX path of SearchDir)
        end SpotlightSearch
```

but what really happens is the script highlights the word "on" the 5th to last line of the code and says Syntax Error:Expected “else”, etc. but found “on”. Can someone please make it so this code is compatible with what I am trying to do? It would be most appreciated

Comment: Do not cross-post the same question on multiple SE sites. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/351186/finding-a-file-in-finder-with-a-script

Answer (score 0):

There isn't enough context to provide a functioning reply, but you are missing the corresponding **end if** statement for your added **if mainReturned = "File"** statement.  It helps a bit if you format and/or comment your code to group things together so that you don't get lost.

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty clear: You have to balance the `if` statement with an `end if` **before** the `SpotlightSearch` handler

```
if mainReturned = "File" then    
   ...
   if theResults is not {""} then
      ...
   else 
      ...
   end if    
end if

on SpotlightSearch(SearchTerm, SearchDir)
    set theResults to paragraphs of ¬
        (do shell script "mdfind " & quoted form of SearchTerm & ¬
            " -onlyin " & quoted form of POSIX path of SearchDir)
end SpotlightSearch
```

Comment: I have an end if statement in the code listed above before the spotlight search handler. Could you please provide more context into where you would expect me to put it?

Comment: The `end if` in your code belongs to `if theResults...else...`, please note the code indentation.

Comment: I tried to incorporate your idea in the script the exact way as stated, but sadly it still doesn't work. The program works fine on its own without the         if mainReturned = "File" then

Comment: I have no idea what `if mainReturned = "File"` is supposed to do. Stand-alone it's pointless because the expression evaluates always to `false`. Where is the variable `mainReturned` defined?

Comment: I tried implementing your idea into my script but it still maintains the same issue. The problem is I want it to activate when I press a button within the app, I don't really want it to stand alone. Thank you for your determination to help!!!!!! If you think of any more ideas or if I am potentially messing up, considering that I am an amateur, please let me know! MOST APPRECIATED

Answer (score 0):

Thank y'all so much for your help and being willing to help!!! I have learned so much from y'all and I love this website and the kindness presented on it. I have found the answer. I needed to create a second script and input it into the applications script folder and then use the command run script file " THANK YOU FOR THE HELP!!!!!!